# No DropdownMenuItem with DropdownButton's value exception thrown, but there actually is one. How do I make equal Lists? Is there an alternative?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been getting an exception at a DropdownButton widget:

```
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: [E4, B3, G3, D3, A2, E2]. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 850 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
```

The DropdownButton's value in this case is a list of strings: `List<String> val = ["E4", "B3", "G3", "D3", "A2", "E2"]`. As can be seen in the exception.

The DropdownMenuItems also contain lists of strings as their values in the same way, through the map of a variable that is a list of these lists (`List<List<String>>`). One of these items is the same as the DropdownButton, as a different variable however.

I have been very confused as to why I'm getting this error, given the condition is supposedly satisfied...

After searching for solutions, the thing that makes the most sense for me right now is the "fact" that lists are not equal despite having the same elements, which means that the equality is not evaluated in the same way as other types and will return false even though 2 lists have the same content. Which would explain this exception.

I can think of 2 immediate solutions, but both of them are troublesome:

1. The most problematic one, but also easier, which would be to modify Flutter's base code in order to adapt the assertion to consider Lists  with the same elements as equal;
2. The less problematic one, but surely more complicated and troublesome, which would be to either change the types of these lists and handle them in a different manner  or create classes for them

Maybe I misunderstood something and/or there are simpler ways to do this.

Please correct me if I'm wrong! Any help is very much appreciated, thank you for reading!

PS: This code used to work in an older Flutter/Dart version, at the end of 2019. Maybe this issue is somehow related to null safety or some other updates?

Comment: Can you add the code for how the `Dropdown` was created ?

Comment: Dart uses the `hashCode` and `==` operator to check for equality. So you have a third option, that is to extend List and override the `hashCode` and `==` operator. See [hashCode property](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html) for More info

Comment: @RohanThacker It's a little big for the post, so I posted the relevant code on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/raw/6306Shbk (without some unimportant parts)

Comment: To confirm, The errors you posted above are a set of 2 errors? That is 1. Value not found in the DropdownMenuItem values and 2. Either zero or 2 or more?

Comment: @RohanThacker It's a single error. There's a dropdown button which has a default value, when you open the dropdown button it should show the other options, each with their respective values. The error basically says that there's no option (when you open the menu) with the same value as the default option's value.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem. But I solved it like this:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> val = ["E4", "B3", "G3", "D3", "A2", "E2"];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FormField<int>(
      builder: (FormFieldState<int> state) {
        return InputDecorator(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 16.0),
              hintText: "hints",
              border:
                  OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
          isEmpty: state.value == null,
          child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: DropdownButton<int>(
              value: state.value,
              isDense: true,
              onChanged: (int? newValue) {
                state.didChange(newValue);
                print(val[newValue!]);
              },
              items: List<int>.generate(val.length, (index) => index)
                  .map<DropdownMenuItem<int>>((int value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(val[value]),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In your case the value is an integer, in mine it's the list itself. I'm pretty sure that's the reason for the problem.

Comment: here I use list of int so that every time the list value remain same. But look at the onChange method. I can do whatever I want in that function because every time when the value is changed I can access the main list selected item(val[newValue]). In this case I just simply print that main list item value.

Comment: The logic in other parts of the program depends on these values for me, if I changed that I'd have to change the whole program.

Comment: There's a sample of this widget that I commented above: https://pastebin.com/raw/6306Shbk | If you want the whole code I can give you an older version which is almost the same: https://github.com/Slins-23/flutter-guitar-tuner